# Summary row for a dynamic EXT.NET GridPanel

Tags: c#, .net, extjs, ext.net

I'm building an application that displays some results in a grid.
The grid is created dynamically, in the C# code behind. I'm using the following code to display grouping on the grid. But I'd also like to have a summary row. I've tried this with a plugin but it doesn't seem to work.

```
private GroupingView group = new GroupingView();

group.ID = "gv1";
group.HideGroupedColumn = true;

group.GroupTextTpl = "{text} ({[values.rs.length]} {[values.rs.length > 1 ? \"Items\" : \"Item\"]})";
group.EnableRowBody = true;

GridPanelResults.View.Add(group);

GroupingSummary gsPlugin = new GroupingSummary();

GridPanelResults.Plugins.Add(gsPlugin);
```

This is the summary row I need
http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/...oupingSummary/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea: you must set SummaryType or CustomSummaryType for columns in your grid. CustomSummaryType is a JavaScript code that will calculate summary. SummaryType is a standart functions of calculation.

If you will choose CustomSummaryType you will need add Calculations (collection of JS functions) for GroupingSummary.

Comment: thanks! i create the grid dinamically, by adding ColumnBase objects to the ColumnModel. So they don't have a summary type

Comment: Try use GroupingSummaryColumn: `var column = new GroupingSummaryColumn { SummaryType = SummaryType.Count }; grid.ColumnModel.Columns.Add(column);`

Comment: If you could not use GroupingSummaryColumn - you can add custom config to ColumnBase. `var columnBase = new Column();
            (columnBase as ColumnBase).CustomConfig.Add(new ConfigItem("summaryType", "max"));`. Standart functions are "max", "sum", "average", "count".